# How to I remove whole line highlighting in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want VSCode line highlight to look like this
[image: Text]

Currently, it looks like this
[image: Text]

Basically I dont want VSCode to highlight the entire line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this to your `settings.json` (global or project)

```json
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#00000000"
  },
```

Set the line highlight to a transparent color

Comment: This is closer to what I wanted but both answers were helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Look at the options for this setting:

`Editor: Render Line Highlight`

options are `none`, `gutter`, `line` and `all`

You cannot just highlight the text part of the line.  If that is what you want, look at the `gutter` option perhaps.  If you just want to reduce the obviousness of the highlight, use @rioV8's answer - the last two digits in the hex are opacity.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks