# How to change a user setting in VSCode based on the theme (dark or light)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I changed my current line setting based on the answer from this question: [How to highlight current line number in Visual Studio Code / VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64880456/how-to-highlight-current-line-number-in-visual-studio-code-vs-code)

Now it looks good when using a light theme.
[image]

But when I switch to a dark theme, it looks badly like this.
[image]

How can I define different `workbench.colorCustomizations` for dark and light theme differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the theme name, AFAIK the json editor suggests theme names if you type `"[`

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#ffffff",
    "[One Dark Pro]": {
      "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#ff0000",
    }
  },
```